# is there a homebrew equivalent of dnf provides?

Tags: homebrew

I am on OSX 13.4.1 and I am using homebrew as my package manager.  I want to find all packages that provide `cdefs.h`.  In RHEL, you can use `dnf provides */cdefs.h` to search for the package that provides a particular file.

QUESTION :

1. Is there an equivalent way to use homebrew to search for the package that provides  a specific file?

Comment: It seems not https://superuser.com/q/781693/363732